# How can I create a docker container from a Dockerfile in github inside a Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Dockerfile in a github repo.
I need to setup my workspace in a certain way and for this I would like to use the Dockerfile.

I cannot seem to find any clear example of a Jenkinsfile that will create the container as a separate stage of the pipeline.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Given you're using pipeline (jenkinsfile) syntax, this is what building a docker image looks like (the simplest way of doing it):

```
stage('Build Docker Image') 
{
    DOCKER_TAG = "my_tag"
     docker.withRegistry("${my_docker_registry}")
     {
       sh "docker build -t ${DOCKER_IMAGE}:${DOCKER_TAG}"
     }
}
```

If you want to build the container then test it, you will need to store a reference to the container, and you can do that with the following code:

```
stage('Build Docker Image') 
{
    DOCKER_TAG = "my_tag"
     docker.withRegistry("${my_docker_registry}")
     {
       var my_image = docker.build("${DOCKER_IMAGE}:${DOCKER_TAG}")

       my_image.inside
       {
         sh "echo 'Hello World'"
       }

       my_image.push()
     }
}
```

Note that if you are using a docker image to run your pipeline, you will need to expose the docker daemon through to the image to build your image (there is an "image all the way down" joke here somewhere...)